# Having Problems Launching A Gazebo Empty World. Help?

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**[All Error Messages are In Bold]**

citizen10@pike:~/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ roslaunch '/home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/launch/empty_world.launch'
... logging to /home/citizen10/.ros/log/d4e35114-fa1c-11e2-b4a3-20cf3092860b/roslaunch-pike-14262.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http: //pike:38054/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosdistro
- /rosversion
- /use_sim_time

NODES
/
gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http: //localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [14286]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [14294]
/home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo: 15: /home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo: /home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzserver: not found
**[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 14286, exit code 127, cmd /home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/citizen10/.ros/log/d4e35114-fa1c-11e2-b4a3-20cf3092860b/gazebo-1.log].**
**log file: /home/citizen10/.ros/log/d4e35114-fa1c-11e2-b4a3-20cf3092860b/gazebo-1*.log**
/home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: 10: /home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: /home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzclient: not found
**[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 14294, exit code 127, cmd /home/citizen10/ros_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/citizen10/.ros/log/d4e35114-fa1c-11e2-b4a3-20cf3092860b/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/citizen10/.ros/log/d4e35114-fa1c-11e2-b4a3-20cf3092860b/gazebo_gui-2*.log**
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70513/having-problems-launching-a-gazebo-empty-world.-help?/) by [Citizen10](https://answers.ros.org/users/5701/citizen10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2013-08-01**:
Which version of gazebo are you running? and with which ROS distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install Synaptic Package Manager and install simulator_gazebo from that. and run the following command.

```
$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

I hope it will work fine.

Note: run the ros master before running above command

```
$ roscore
```

---

Originally posted by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) with karma: 205 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0